# What does the `-f' option do for `wait' versus the default behaviour?

Tags: bash, wait

Bash 5.0 includes a new `-f` option for `wait`:<sup>[[1]](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-5.0)</sup>

```
j. The `wait' builtin now has a `-f' option, which signfies to wait until the
   specified job or process terminates, instead of waiting until it changes
   state.
```

What does `wait -f $pid` do as opposed to the default `wait $pid`? Under what conditions is the `-f` option needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change description is accurate, but somewhat obscure since `wait` is generally thought of as [waiting for a process to finish](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wait.html).

Try this:

```
sleep 60&
wait %1
```

then in another terminal,

```
kill -STOP ${pid}
```

replacing `${pid}` with `sleep`’s pid (as output when it was put in the background). `wait` will exit, because the job’s state changed.

With `-f`, `wait` will wait for the job or process to really terminate; used above, it wouldn’t exit with `kill -STOP`, and would wait for the process to be resumed (`kill -CONT`) and finish running.

Comment: At least with bash 4.3, this wait-for-any-state-change behavior happens only if the shell is interactive. In a script, fortunately, bash behaves as other shells: wait for the process to terminate.

Comment: @Gilles is the behaviour in an interactive shell vs. a non-interactive one documented anywhere? `help wait` doesn't mention that difference.

Comment: @Whymarrh Not in the documentation of 4.3. I haven't checked if it's been fixed in 5.0.

Comment: @Whymarrh The online manual says "when job control is enabled", which by default is the case for an interactive shell. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html